# Can I use node.js with Objective-J?

Tags: node.js, objective-j

I would like to write a web application using node.js and Cappuccino. I want to write the back-end in Objective-J, just like the front-end.

Can I use node.js with Objective-J? What is needed to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to use Objective-J on the server :( You can use javascript instead

Comment: @Raynos Why not? Objective-J is awesome.

Comment: @Raynos why would I debug compiled Objective-J?

Comment: @Raynos Objective-J can be easily debugged. I don't see the problem. You don't even need to compile Objective-J before you can use it.

Comment: I'm making broad assumptions about Objective-J. I don't know whether you can use it with node.js, but you should be able to.

Answer (score 1):

beeing a professional Objective-J coder I can say it is definitely possible since Objective-J is fully based on JavaScript. But I also have to say that I never tried it.

I think it would be a good idea to directly start a discussion in the official Objective-J Google Group:

http://groups.google.com/group/objectivej

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://bitbucket.org/clbruno/objj-node/overview

Comment: Unfortunately, that link is very dead